# IS_REAL for subtraction of words in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one column called newspaper_cd, which can be A129 or FHID for example. I need to firstly extract the three digits from the right side, and then add a conditional expression in snowflake. The issue is that the current column is in string, even though the right 3 digits is a number, it is still regarded as a string.

```
case when is_real(to_variant(right(newspaper_cd,3))) = True then 1 else 0
---  I got all 0s, because it is a string column

--- If I change it for a number thinking about the case like A129
to_number(right(newspaper_cd,3))
--- 'HID' is not recognized for 'FHID'
```

So how should I deal with it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [TRY_TO_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_decimal.html):

```
SELECT newspaper_cd, TRY_TO_NUMBER(right(newspaper_cd,3)) IS NOT NULL
FROM tab
```

Output:

```
A129  True
FHID  False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also apply SUBSTR on column having varchar like below

```
select
    CASE
        WHEN IS_REAL(TO_NUMBER(substr(newspaper_cd, -3, 3))) = TRUE THEN 1
        else 0
    end;
```